# Remove common code from functions

Tags: java

I got nearly 10 functions in class having similar pattern like following function

```
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
          //Some different code , all other code(try,catch,finally) is same in all functions
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }

}
```

I want to remove that common code from all functions (try ,catch , finally) and move it to a single place
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You write a helper method.

Comment: If the code in the `try` is different, you aren't going to be able to usefully refactor it. The better pattern is to put *all* of your database interactions into a separate class(es)/set of methods so you almost never have to look at it.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: it could be refactored using an interface (with a single method) which is then passed to the helper method.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, but I don't consider that to be a useful refactor, since it adds more boilerplate than it eliminates.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Yup I agree with you

Comment: @ChrisHayes: I don't think it would add a huge amount of boilerplate in this case using anonymous inner classes - and of course as soon as Java 8 comes out, refactoring those anonymous inner classes to lambda expressions would shrink it down further.

Comment: @JonSkeet True, but I personally find anonymous inner classes harder to read than a simple try/catch. I think it would be largely subjective. Agreed about lambdas, but you could be waiting quite a while for Java 8 to work its way into many corporate environments (and even longer for team members not used to lambdas to accept it!). :)

Comment: @ChrisHayes: The difference is that it's unlikely that the syntax for the anonymous inner class will need to change. Whereas if you need to change anything about the other boiler plate (e.g. exactly how you're logging) it means changing every single one of those methods. And it's not just a try/catch - it's an "acquire database connection" then try/catch/finally, and getting any of that wrong is going to cause pain.

Comment: @Raheel what is the class of `this` in `this.getWritableDatabase()`? is it `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` or something else?

Comment: @ADTC its "SQLiteOpenHelper"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of frameworks out there that drastically simplify database interaction that you can use, but if you want to do things on your own, and are interested in the Java way to do things like this, here's the idea:

Make your "executor" like so:

```
public class Executor {
  public static void runOperation(Operation operation) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
      operation.run(database);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
      Log.e(operation.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
      return false;
    } finally {
      database.close();
  }
}
```

Now each of the 10 things you want to do will be operations:

```
public interface Operation {
  void run(SQLiteDatabase database) throws SQLiteException;
}
```

Here is what a particular operation would look like:

```
Operation increaseSalary = new Operation() {
  public void run(SQLiteDatabase database) throws SQLiteException {
    // .... write the new increased salary to the database
  }
};
```

And you run it with:

```
.
.
Executor.runOperation(increaseSalary);
.
.
```

You can also make the implementation of the interface an anonymous inner class, but that may make it a little less readable.

```
.
.
Executor.runOperation(new Operation() {
  public void run(SQLiteDatabase database) throws SQLiteException {
    // put the increase salary database-code in here
  }
});
.
.
```

You can look through a list of classic Design Patterns to find out which one this is.

Comment: I think you should put `Operation.run(database);` inside the `try` block... isn't that the intention?

Comment: And also declare `throws SQLiteException`.

Comment: The anonymous inner class will help avoid creating a *separate* class file for each operation. So his original class with 10 or so functions can remain the same way, except being refactored to use the `Executor` pattern. So in a way, it can be more readable as all the *"something"* code are still in the same place, not moved to separate class files.

Comment: Btw one more thing I noticed, is `this` in Executor. I think this should be changed to a private object populated by a constructor, since the original `this` referred to the original class the asker is referring to, not `Executor` class. Or **better,** pass it as an argument to the static method, in addition to the `Operation` object: `Executor.runOperation(this, new Operation() { ...`

Comment: @ADTC Even anonymous inner classes generate additional class files (ending in `$1.class`, `$2.class`, etc.)  I say _may_ be less readable because naming your subclasses can increase readability.  If an operation needs to be defined to increase someone's salary, for example, one can define `Operation increaseSalary = new Operation () {...}` and later say `runOperation(increaseSalary)`.  That IMHO is better than jamming in the increase salary logic in the middle of a larger operation. After all, that's why we write and name functions in the first place. :)

Comment: Yes that is true. Well anyway, I was talking from a source code perspective, in case the asker did not want to move the source code out into separate files - but on second thought, he could create all the classes in one source file too as inner classes. `:)` *There are so many ways to tackles this!*

Comment: @ADTC You are correct that I overlooked the use of `this`. Thanks again!  I've changed my answer, but I think I've done it in such a way as to avoid passing the reference around.  The variable `operation` is accessible so we can get its class in the exception handler.  Does that look okay?

Comment: Actually no, it's not `operation` but it's `SQLiteOpenHelper` as evidenced by asker's recent comment. Please see my answer on how I tackled the `this` problem. Also, the return type of the original methods is `boolean`, not `void`. *Let's avoid extended discussions.. S.O. is beating the drums already `:)`*

Answer (score 1):

**To expand further on [Ray Toal's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20931708/1134080),** it is worth noting that using anonymous inner class will help avoid creating a separate class file for each operation. So the original class with 10 or so functions can remain the same way, except being refactored to use the `Executor` pattern.

Also, when using the `Executor` pattern, you have to take care of the usage of `this` in the original code. Assume the original functions are as follows:

```
public boolean operation1() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        //Code for Operation 1
        return true;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }

}

public boolean operation2() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        //Code for Operation 2
        return true;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }

}
```

With the `Executor` class defined as follows:

```
public class Executor {
  public static boolean runOperation(SQLiteOpenHelper helper, Operation operation) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
      operation.run(database);
      return true;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
      Log.e(helper.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
      return false;
    } finally {
      database.close();
    }
  }
}
```

And the `Operation` interface defined as follows:

```
public interface Operation {
    public void run(SQLiteDatabase database) throws SQLiteException;
}
```

The original functions can now be rewritten as follows:

```
public boolean operation1() {
    return Executor.runOperation(this, new Operation() {
      public void run(SQLiteDatabase database) throws SQLiteException {
        //Code for Operation 1
      }
    });
}

public boolean operation2() {
    return Executor.runOperation(this, new Operation() {
      public void run(SQLiteDatabase database) throws SQLiteException {
        //Code for Operation 2
      }
    });
}
```

*This expansion also corrects mistakes Ray has overlooked in his original answer.*